# I cannot load my Static JS in an Express server

Tags: javascript, express

I'm pretty miffed with this one, it seems to be a well answered issue, and my code seems legit, but I'm not seeing the problem . . .

I have a .js file to connect to my survey page, and have it added as such at the bottom of the `<body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/questions.js"></script>
```

In server.js I've tried this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('data'));
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use('/static', express.static('data'));
```

really covering the bases there . . .  'public' is where the html pages lie, data where my json and .js files.

Tree:

```
root
-app
--data
--public
server.js
```

but I am continuing to get a failure to load js error.

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

What gives, man?

Comment: A question is why is there a request for `http://localhost:8080/app/data/questions.js` (that naturally gives an error because there's no `express.static()` that covers that) when you say the `<script>` tag is `/static/questions.js`.  That doesn't sound right.  So, something you're telling us isn't correct here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you didn't send the js file to the user when a request is received in the server

Eg: we need js file named as public.js

file path: ui/publish.js

request : http//:localhost:4000/ui/publish.js

```
app.get('/ui/publish.js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'publish.js'));
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Structure 
root
-app
--data
  -- a.js
  -- b.js
--public
   -- a.html
server.js


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('data'));
```

Now your url for accessing a.js is `http://localhost:8080/a.js` and html `http://localhost:8080/a.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/questions.js"></script>
```

you should modify your script tag like this and add the below line in server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app/public')));
```

put your js files in the `/app/public` folder

Comment: I think this is the best approach to serve static files in ExpressJS